# WPF view only binding to first viewmodel when using datatemplate and contentcontrol for view navigation

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement a TreeView where clicking different levels will open different views, in the same window, to be able to edit them.

When I select an item and update its value it works as expected. But after that when I select a different item it won't update as intended. It almost seem to cache the button to the first view somehow. I can't even update the first element ever again after switching to something else. I want the view to re-render/re-bind for each time I select a node in the tree.

[image]

Parent view:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SurfaceViewModel}">
        <local:SurfaceView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SpaceViewModel}">
        <local:SpaceView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" />
```

Parent view model:

```
public void NodeChanged()
{
    SelectedViewModel = null;

    if (showSpace)
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new SpaceViewModel(selectedNode.Space);
    }
    else if (showSurface)
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new SurfaceViewModel(selectedNode.Surface);
    }
}

...

private object _selectedViewModel;

public object SelectedViewModel
{
    get { return _selectedViewModel; }
    set
    {
        _selectedViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel")
    }
}
```

SurfaceView:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType}" ... />
<Button Content="Save changes" ... />
```

SurfaceViewModel:

```
public HeatLossSurface _updateSurface { get; set; }

public SurfaceViewModel(HeatLossSurface updateSurface)
{
    _updateSurface = updateSurface;
}

public void SaveChanges()
{
    _updateSurface.SurfaceType = SelectedType;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding something here...

Comment: you have problem with TreeView, but there is no TreeView in code. no [mcve] - no solution

Comment: I've stripped unnecessary parts. You have the code for when a node is selected instead (NodeChanged). Do you really need the XAML for the TreeView as well?